# Angular execute condition before controller loads

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an application where i use a main ctr called `AppCtrl'that i use to share some global vars, helpers and data.

I also have one controller for each view so each time the user refresh the page or enter in my app for the first time i need to do some tasks in a certain order but those are in separated controllers.

For example, in the `AppCtrl` i need to load some user data from my database but i need that the route or the secondary controller, lets call him `HomeCtrl`, waits for this before it can load it's content since it dependes on the info from `AppCtrl`.

I'm using the `$scope` var to share the data between controllers.

So, how could i make `HomeCtrl` wait for the end of `AppCtrl` execution to start its processing ?

**EDIT:**

I have created a pastebin, http://pastebin.com/CUtTmKzT, to share my `AppCtrl` and an example of my `HomeCtrl`. For clarity sake i have removed a lot of content and only left some signatures so you can understand what i'm trying to achieve.

To explain it better, i want to execute some methods on every page load that will query some data from my api and share it between all my controllers. I can only do this once since the application will be heavily used.

So, following my **pastebin** code i have the method `handleLoginSuccess` that will be called once the user has accessed the app, it will check if the user data exists on my `$rootScope`, if it does it will call a method to process this data, `setCurrentUser`, and if it doesn't it will call a method to query this data from the api, `getUserData`, and then call the other method to process it.

Comment: you have a few gaps in knowledge of the angular framework here that will make this very difficult.  Firstly, the `$digest` cycle that renders the HTML is not tied to the order that controllers load.  Secondly. each controller has it's own `$scope`, so using `$scope` to "share" data can potentially create some nasty to troubleshoot bugs.  You may want to re-think your architecture here, and consider using directives or components instead, or use a router to manage your views.

Comment: @Claies, could you please provide some example of how i could use a directive or components to share the data ? Because i don't see how they could share it between controllers without using scope and without hitting the database all the time. Also, i wasn't talking about html render but methods execution

Comment: well, sharing data is better left to providers (services or factories, usually), which are singleton objects.  I only mention directives and components because you are trying to imply a hierarchical nature to your HTML here, which controllers don't directly strictly adhere to.

Comment: Oh no, i don't want the HTML to load in some sort of order, actually i don't mind it, what i do mind is the methods order since i need the data shared on several controllers and it has to be loaded from the DB only once so how could i do it in the `correct` way ? I have some services running here and they do hit the database all the time, actually in every request (state change)

Comment: ok so now the question is becoming a bit clearer;  you are trying to figure out how to manage the data so that you don't make your database calls multiple times.  That sounds like it's more related to how your services are designed, and not really about the `$scope` or the HTML code in your question at all.  Seeing how your services are, and how your controllers call these services would help make more sense of this.

Comment: Yes, that's right ! I will create some fiddle to share the code and edit my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide/blob/master/a1/README.md

^Best guide to use Angular. Also I would look into some tutorials on how $scope is used.

The way I learned angular, and am still learning, is to think of things in components. This limits dependency issues and weird digest issues within angular.

Comment: Yeah, that's what i also learned but i kind of lost myself on this because i have this data that has to be shared everywhere and i can't hit the DB all the time and also can't save it on cookies or store since it's quite big. Thanks and i will take a look into the guide

Comment: It sounds like you may need to create a Service that is touching the DB and then you can use that service among other controllers, if need be. I like to keep things as separate as possible so I do not have coupling issues.

Comment: Yes, that's what i did, i have several of those and i also had one for this data but i had to decrease the database hits. If i use the service i need to 'save' the data somewhere so i don't have to hit it again right ? How can i do that with services and without using '$scope' ?

Comment: This answer does not answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

```
In 1st controller like AppCtrl,you can pass the data like:

$rootScope.$broadcast('scanner-started', { any: {} });

then in second controller HomeCtrl,you can fetch the data like-

$scope.$on('scanner-started', function(event, args) {
    var anyThing = args.any;
    // do what you want to do
});
```

Comment: That wont work since i have many methods that are executed at the same time in the `HomeCtrl`, i need the controller execution/start wait for the end of the `AppCtrl`. This also doesn't sound like a good alternative because i would need to add lots of listeners.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you should take a look on ngRoute or ui-router. Ui-router have nested states those share date from parent state to child one. And you be able to resolve some promises from parent state and decide allow user to child state or you maybe you wonna redirect user to login state. https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Nested-States-and-Nested-Views

Comment: I tried that but my 'HomeCtrl' still executes before the `AppCtrl`. I created an abstract state called `main` and moved my `home` state to `main.home` and placed the controller of the main state as `AppCtrl`. Should i do anything different ?